# Execute code within a factory when needed, not when loaded into controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-services, angular-http, angular-controller

Factory:

```
.factory("myFac", ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {  
    var defer = $q.defer();

    $http.get('some/sample/url').then(function (response) { //success
        /* 
         * Do something with response that needs to be complete before
         * controller code is executed.
         */
        defer.resolve('done');
    }, function() { //error
        defer.reject();
    });

    return defer.promise;
}]);
```

Controller:

```
.controller("testCtrl", ['$scope', 'myFac', function($scope, myFac) {
    /*
    * Factory code above is executed immediately as 'myFac' is loaded into controller.
    * I do not want this.
    */

    if($scope.someArbitraryBool === true) {
        //THIS is when I want to execute code within myFac
        myFac.then(function () {
            //Execute code that is dependent on myFac resolving
        });
    } 
}]);
```

Please let me know if it is possible to delay the code in the factory until I need it. Also, if there's a better way to execute on this concept, feel free to correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You factory has `$http.get` directly inside factory function which return custom $q promise. So while you inject the factory dependency inside your controller function, it ask angular to create an object of `myFac` factory function, while creating object of function it executes the code block which you have returned your factory, basically which returns promise.

What you could do is, just return a object `{}` from the factory function which will have method name with its definition, so when you inject inside angular controller it will return service object, which will various method like `getData` method. And whenever you want to call the method of factory you could do `factoryName.methodName()` like `myFac.getData()`.

Also you have created a extra promise inside your service which is not needed in first place, as you can utilize the promise of `$http.get` (which returns a promise object.)

**Factory**

```
.factory("myFac", ['$http', function($http) {
    var getData = return $http.get('some/sample/url').then(function (response) { //success
        return 'done'; //return to resolve promise with data.
    }, function(error) { //error
        return 'error'; //return to reject promise with data.
    });

    return {
        getData: getData
    };

}]);
```

**Controller**

```
.controller("testCtrl", ['$scope', 'myFac', function($scope, myFac) {    
    if($scope.someArbitraryBool === true) {
        //Here you could call the get data method.
        myFac.getData().then(function () {
            //Execute code that is dependent on myFac resolving
        });
    } 
}]);
```